# Android - Resizing View programmatically using animation library

Tags: android, animation, resize, size, scale

im trying to resize an imageview using animations from (0,0) to (mLayout.getWidth()/5,mLayout.getHeight()/5) and align it in the center of the screen 
I have tried doing  this by constantly changing the layout params of my ImageView until the width and height are correct but this uses WAY TO MUCH process power and memory !
I have already tried doing this by using scaleAnimation but i cant understand how to resize its height and width from 0 to (let's say) 150 keeping the image strictly in the center of the screen ,using the constructor:

```
 public ScaleAnimation (float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float pivotYValue)
```

More specifically i cant understand which values should i give to the variables : fromX,toX,froY,toY,pivotXValue,pivotYValue.
My code so far is :

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {

public Animation ScaleAnimation(int fromX, int toX,int fromY,int toY,int pivotXValue,int pivotYValue,int Time) {
    Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(
          fromX,
          toX,
          fromY,
          toY,
          ABSOLUTE,
          pivotXValue,
          ABSOLUTE,
          pivotYValue
    );

    scale.setDuration(Time);



    return scale;
}
```

}

thank you for your help

Comment: you can use valueAnimation , that change your height and width from current value to your target value

Comment: @MHP i forgot to mention that im using API 8 (Android 2.2) so thats not an option :(

Comment: The from/to values are the scaling from and to which the view must be animated on the X and Y axis. 0.0f means infinitely small, 1.0f means original size, 2.0f twice the original size, etc.... The pivot is the point in which the scaling should be centered, in your case, the center of your screen.

Comment: you can use nineOld library for that

Comment: @Wildcopper so if i call the call the animation like that :

ResizeAnimation animation = null;
        animation = new ResizeAnimation();
        Animation a=animation.ScaleAnimation(0,40,0,40,DataBase.Layout_Width/2,DataBase.Layout_Height/2,1000);
where 0 is the starting height and width and 40 the final will it work ? cause it doesnt show anything :( thank you

Comment: 40 means the view would get 40x it's default size. That could be huge. Remember, 1.0f means original size. And you can create the animation with just animation = new ScaleAnimation( parameters ); then you can view.startAnimation(animation);

Comment: @Wildcopper before i start the animation i set the image height and width with layoutparams to 1 and then i want to increase that size 40 times but it still doesnt show anything 
 my code looks like that now :

Comment: iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iv_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1,1);
        iv_params.height=1;
        iv_params.width=1;
        iv.setLayoutParams(iv_params);
        animation = new ResizeAnimation();
        System.out.println(iv.getHeight());
        Animation a=animation.ScaleAnimation(1.0f,2.0f,1.0f,2.0f,DataBase.Layout_Width/2,DataBase.Layout_Height/2,1000);
        iv.startAnimation(a);

Comment: Have you used oView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); so that the image sticks to the size of the containing view? I'm the main developer of an Android Digital Signage application, and I use scale animations all over the place - they work well!

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids you can use this library and use animation in all api